# Can't place iframe directly beneath h1

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a profile for a site I use a lot.  I have most everything figured out, with the exception of the placement of an `iframe`.
I'd like it positioned like a double-space distance beneath my **h1**.

Here **h1** is positioned as `such: style="position:absolute;top;75;` `align=center`

... I'd like the `iframe` to be positioned right below it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post your current code for the `h1` and `iframe` and explain more? "double-space" isn't really a standard unit. What are your trying top achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <h1>Something</h1>
  <iframe href="#"></iframe>
</div>

h1{your-style-here}
iframe{ position: relative}
```